# What is the traditional interpretation of Dt. 18:18?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, navi-prophets, parashas-shoftim

The Torah contains a prophecy of a future Prophet who will be like Moses:

> I will raise them up a prophet from among their brethren, like unto thee; and I will put My words in his mouth, and he shall speak unto them all that I shall command him.  ([Deuteronomy 18:18](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0518.htm))

Has this prophecy already been fulfilled? and what are the commentaries on this verse?

I would be more glad to know interpretations which are as old/ancient as possible (old here could mean older than 1000 years).

Comment: Ali, see [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26425/can-a-prophet-add-to-or-change-the-torah)

Answer (score 9):

If you look at the context in the passage, it doesn't appear to be speaking of a single prophet but instead of something that God would do many times through history. 18:10-11 speaks of the option to use divination and other kinds of magic to find things out, but verse 13 says the nation with whom God made a covenant should be wholeheartedly devoted to Him; not to do those things. So in the verse you quoted, God promised to provide a prophet from Himself. The people could listen to this prophet while remaining loyal to the ways of God.

The following verses speak of true prophets and false prophets, and how to tell the difference each time someone claims to be one of these people like Moses. So a fair and probably strong reading of this passage is that yes, the prophecy has been fulfilled, with every true prophet whom God allowed to be recognised by the righteous people among Israel.