Does Deut. 34:10 mean that Joshua wasn’t the prophet like Moses?
I used to think Deuteronomy 18:18

I will raise them up a prophet from among their brethren, like you, and will put My words in his mouth

was about Jesus but I see the Jews believe it’s about Joshua which makes a lot of sense after reading Joshua 1.
However, my confusion comes in when Deuteronomy 34:10

And there arose not a prophet since in Yisra᾽el like Moshe, whom the Lord knew face to face

is read because it seems to indicate that the prophet like Moses has to speak directly to יהוה like Moses did.
Does Deut. 34:10 mean that Joshua wasn’t the prophet like Moses? If not Joshua, who is the prophet described in Deut. 18:18?

It's saying no other prophet is comparable to Moses. That would include Joshua. What's unclear exactly?

Also, I would suggest you [edit] the post to remove the Christianity details, since they're immaterial to the question and we don't discuss comparative religion here.

I cleared up your question and noticed that the verse attested that Moses was one of a kind because of his direct interaction with God, whatever that could mean. unlike other prophets who communicated more "remotely". As in Num 12.8 "With him I speak mouth to mouth, plainly and not in riddles, and he beholds the likeness of יהוה.". So what's the question?

@Jack I've fiurther edited the question to make more explicit what I think it is that you're asking. If I've got your intent wrong, please feel free to revert. And welcome!

Very relevant: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/26411/what-is-the-traditional-interpretation-of-dt-1818?rq=1

The prophet who immediately succeeded Moses as leader was Joshua, and this bestowal of leadership begins in Numbers 27:15-23. As you mentioned, we indeed see the Almighty speak prophetically to Joshua in Joshua 1:1-9, and He was with Joshua as He was with Moses (3:7).
Nonetheless, the context of Deuteronomy 18 indicates that it is not only about Joshua, but about a series of true prophets who would continue to guide the Children of Israel throughout many future generations. As such, the singular word "נביא" (prophet) is referring to a template for a class of true prophets. Likewise, 18:19-22 speaks in a parallel manner of a template of false prophets who must be rejected, and the singular "נביא" is used even though such false prophets arose in multiple later generations (see, e.g., I Kings 22 and Jeremiah 28:10-17).
As you mentioned, Moses had a sui generis type of prophecy ("face to face") that would never be achieved by anyone else (Deut. 34:10-12). Various commentators have addressed the meaning of "like you" in Deut. 18:15,18, and some of them point out explicitly that the similarity of this prophet to Moses does not extend to the advanced level of prophecy that Moses achieved.1
Targum Yerushalmi (Deut. 18:15, "דְּדָמֵי לִי בְּרוּחַ קוּדְשָׁא") explains the similarity to be that the future prophets will be infused with a prophetic spirit of holiness.
Rashi (ad loc., "כמו שאני מקרבך מאחיך יקים לך תחתי וכן מנביא לנביא") explains the point of similarity to be that future prophets will be like Moses insofar as they will emerge from the brethren within the Children of Israel. Thus, Rashi reads the verse as, "A prophet who will be from your midst, from your brethren, [and as such will be] like me."
Rashbam (ad loc.) explains that the prophet will be like Moses in exhorting the Children of Israel to follow the Torah, unlike a false prophet or dreamer who tells Israel to worship idolatry. The Rashbam adds that Deut. 34:10 should be interpreted to read, "And no other prophet arose in Israel like Moses, [insofar as] he knew the Lord face to face," while prophets would arise who would be similar to Moses in other respects.
Ibn Ezra (ad loc., "כמוני שהוא נביא השם לא מנחש") provides a similar explanation that future true prophets would be prophets of the Almighty, and not sorcerous diviners.
The Ramban (ad loc., "וכן על דעתי 'כמוני' שיהיה נאמן לנביא לה' ותאמין בו כאשר אתה מאמין בי") provides a similar explanation, that the true prophets would be similar to Moses insofar as being a faithful prophet of the Almighty, and that the Children of Israel should trust in such a prophet just as they trusted in Moses.
Rabbeinu Bechaye (ad loc.) explains that the prophet described in Deut. 18:15,18 is Joshua, but can also include the series of later prophets who would guide Israel. Rabbeinu Bechaye provides an explanation of "like me" which is similar to Rashi's explanation, and Rabbeinu Bechaye explains that the repeated language is necessary to drive home the point that future prophets for Israel would not merely emerge from distant "brethren" (namely the descendants of Esau or Ishmael), but only from the Children of Israel themselves.
Rabbeinu Bechaye also provides another explanation similar to the Rashbam, that future true prophets would never seek to permanently or completely uproot any of the commandments of the Torah, and at most they would have the authority to temporarily suspend observance of a commandment in some cases for certain exigencies (see Y'vamos 90b).
Finally, Rabbeinu Bechaye points out that the Children of Israel believed Moses not because of the miracles Moses performed, but rather because the entire congregation of Israel heard the Almighty's voice together with Moses and therefore knew that later pronouncements they would hear from Moses were from a true and reliable prophet. In a similar vein, the Children of Israel would establish future prophets not on the basis of miracles, but on the basis of verifying their prophecy and thereby establishing them as authentic prophets going forward (see Deut. 18:21-22).

1 The New Testament passage to which you alluded (Acts 3:19-23) is a christological eisegesis that injects Christian interpretation into verses in the Hebrew Bible by ignoring the context of Deut. 18. 
